# How to setTimeout for one of css classes of HTML element?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, settimeout

Can I set timeout that keep on hold for 3 second one of two css classes of element.
The second class of the element appears if the field meets a condition.  But before this class is applied I would like to set a timer that waits 3 seconds.
Example:

```
<?php
$x = rand(1,3);
?>

<div class="first <?php if($x == 1){ echo"second"};?>"></div>
<div class="first <?php if($x == 2){ echo"second"};?>"></div>
<div class="first <?php if($x == 3){ echo"second"};?>"></div>

<script>
If class second exist 
for an element then 
remove/hold/pause it for 
3 seconds and then run it. 
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*What I need*" Ok, so where's your attempt at writing actual JavaScript based on the pseudocode provided? Stack Overflow isn't a place you can dump requirements and get your code written *for* you - you must demonstrate a good-faith attempt at solving this on your own before posting here, in accordance with [ask]. If you have requirements that you need translated into a working end product, I would recommend you hire a developer.

Comment: You're approaching this from the wrong direction, making it way more complicated than it is. You simply need to run a setTimeout call after the page has loaded that adds the 2nd class to the element(s) after three seconds have passed.

Comment: `<?= if($x == 1){ echo"second"};?>` should be `<?php if($x == 1){ echo "second"};?>`. The short tag: `<?=` is the same as `<?php echo` so you have echo twice. Or even easier: `<?= $x == 1 ? 'second' : '' ?>`

Comment: Thank you for the advise. Noted.

Comment: Does your code execute without errors? I think that `<?= if($x == 1){ echo"second"};?>` will throw a runtime error. `<?=` is equal to `<?php echo`, that is, it will only produce an output and not execute procedures. Of course you could use a ternary operator with the first form (`<?=(test) ? (string if true) : (string if false)?>`), or use `<?php ... ?>` and execute more structured code inside it.

Comment: The code is wrong only here, in my file I use <?php ?> with echo and it's work without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you are not expert in javascript and are studying php/html/css, you may try with **CSS animation properties**. Be aware that animation is an advanced topic in general. A better solution might be the javascript one that Mister Jojo provided.

I could understand that:

- you can only put the class in the resulting html
- you need the change to happen after 3 seconds
- the change must happen only once
- the change regards the background color

Following there is a possible implementation, based on the previous assumptions.

```css
.first {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.second {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-duration: 1ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-name: delayChangeColor;
}

@keyframes delayChangeColor {
  to {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first">1</div>
<div class="first second">2</div>
<div class="first">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what to say...?

```js
const
  divEl  = document.querySelectorAll('div.first')
, random = Math.floor( Math.random() * divEl.length)
  ;
divEl[random].classList.add('second')
  ;
setInterval(_=> 
  {
  divEl[random].classList.toggle('second')
  }, 3000);
```

```css
.first {
  width      : 4em;
  height     : 2em;
  background : lightskyblue;
  margin     : .6em 1em; 
  }
.second {
  background : coral;
  }
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="first"></div>
```

Comment: "*what to say...?*" This answer would benefit *significantly* from the inclusion of a succinct explanation of what you've changed, how it differs from the OP's code, and how specifically it solves their problem.

Comment: I am a student in a php, css, html course. JavaScript is in the next level. For my final project I have to make a board game. So I decide that will be cool if i find a way to make curent fild changing it's color after the dice stop rolling (gif file). I was tring JavaScript all day but I have no knowledge in general. And I am also new for this comunity so... all advises are welcome.

Comment: `*3` magic numbers! Why not `divEl.length` :) Also, again, after years, your formatting is pretty bad and unreadable. And that's not subjective. Almost not.